# MDM Zinc Flash Database 'Undefined'

Tags: mdm-zinc

I want to ask why my Text Area produce the text 'undefined'

```
mdm.Database.MySQL.connect("localhost", "3306", true, "root", "adaptasi");

mdm.Database.MySQL.runQuery("SELECT morfo FROM materi");

TextIsi1.text = mdm.Database.MySQL.getData();
```

I use mdm for my flash (swf) project that connect with database.

Answer (score 0):

**Returns**

An Array

**Description**

Returns the full query data to a 2 dimensional array. The first dimension contains the row number and the second dimension contains the field number.

**Notes**

A Query must first be executed with mdm.Database.MySQL.runQuery()

**Example Code**

```
//Prompts the data in Row 1, Field 4:
mdm.Database.MySQL.runQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable")
var dataSet:Array = mdm.Database.MySQL.getData();
mdm.Dialogs.prompt(dataSet[0][3])
//This example will display the entire contents of the specified table in a dialog prompt
var tableName:String = "myTable";
mdm.Database.MySQL.runQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName)
var dataSet:Array = mdm.Database.MySQL.getData();
var myText = ""
for (i=0; i<dataSet.length; i++) {
    for (n=0; n<dataSet[0].length; n++) {
        myText += "FIELD"+(n+1)+" = "+dataSet[i][n]+", ";
    }
    myText += "\n";
}
mdm.Dialogs.prompt(myText);
```

from documentation
your code should be something like:

```
TextIsi1.text = mdm.Database.MySQL.getData()[0][0];
```